# What does the app "Eduroam fixer" do?

Tags: wi-fi

I can connect to my university's eduroam network but very often I lose the connection and cannot reconnect until I reboot the phone. Now I found [an app called "eduroam fixer"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.luqq.eduroamfixer) in the market. What is this app supposed to do exactly, what does it differently to the built-in WPA enterprise support? I cannot properly test the app right now as I'm not anywhere near my campus.

Comment: I use the eduroam network in Erlangen without any problems or extra Apps. You should ask the developer about the App.

Comment: so someone can actually connect to eduroam? I have never been able to do it

Comment: I should add that I'm running ICS and the people I have asked who have Gingerbread cannot connect at all either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the reviews on various sites, this app is unlikely to solve your need to reboot after the connection gets screwed up; users report the same thing occurring with the app.

[This thread](https://www.terena.org/mail-archives/mobility/msg03744.html) is particularly relevant.  It seems that "Eduroam Fixer" is just a configurator.  In particular it allows you connect to Eduroam by changing config files for you; this is useful on some ROMs which (for whatever reason) don't allow you to properly set the certificate through the interface.  I'm not 100% clear on the details, but the people in that thread consider it a security risk.